# Tradingview/ Pine Script/ Tendlines/ Code to draw a trendline 25% above and below an exisiting trendline on a chart

Tags: trading, pine-script, trendline

How do I draw a trengline parallel to existing trendline 25% above and below an existing trendline on a chart in Trading View using Pine Script.

Best Regards
Abhijeet Durge

Answer (score 0):

You could just duplicate the existing line drawing calls and offset their "y"-positioning arguments by 1.25 and 0.75 factors.